# HttpURLConnection with POST "times out" on ICS, works in HC

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My Android tablet application does not work with ICS due to a Login problem.  When I looked at my code and ran it under debug mode on an ICS tablet, I see the problem but I don't understand it.  The code functions correctly on all Honeycomb models that i have tested and in fact I have two tablets hooked up to my computer (one Samsung Galaxy Tab running 3.2, and a Motorola Xoom wifi running 4.0.3) and the code fails on ICS and works on HC.

The failure is a Socket Timeout exception.  The timeout was 2000ms, but I upped it to 100000ms to test and it had no impact.

Using the browser on the ICS tablet, I can go to the URL and it responds, so it doesn't appear to be network related.

I am running on a background thread using AsyncTask.

Slurp just takes all of the input from the InputStream and using StringBuilder creates a string representation.  Its not actually useful in this request but I added it to see what the server was replying with.

I am POSTing to the page the same way a user authenticates using the form, which is why I am using x-www-form-urlencoded.

Again, this code functions perfectly on Honeycomb but fails on ICS.

The code makes a connection but fails when it asks for a response from the server, almost like the server is still waiting for something... anyway, here is the code:

```
static public String authenticate(String service_url, String username, String password) throws IOException {
    if (username == null || password == null)
        throw new IOException();

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String query = String.format("Email=%s&Password=%s",URLEncoder.encode(username, charset),URLEncoder.encode(password, charset));
    byte [] data = query.getBytes(charset);

    URL url = new URL(service_url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length));

    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000); // 2 second timeout.


    try {
        connection.connect();

        DataOutputStream pw = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream());
        pw.writeBytes(query);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();

        int code = connection.getResponseCode(); //SOCKET TIMEOUT HERE
        if (code == 200 || code == 302)
        {
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            String value = slurp(is);

            List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
            if (cookies == null)
                throw new IOException();

            for (String cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.startsWith("cpms")) {
                    cookieTime = new DateTime();  //crazy but the expires time in the cookie is not actually accurate.
                    return cookie; // this is the only correct path out.
                }
            }
        }
        else
            Logger.e(StaticUtils.class, "Invalid response code while logging in: " + code);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Logger.e(StaticUtils.class, ioe);
        throw ioe; // log it and then throw it back.        
    } finally {
           connection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you get null here?: connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");